# The definability of set of theorems of a theory T which is a consistent extension of Q

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have difficulty understanding lemma 17.2 in page 221 while reading "Computability and Logic" fifth edition by George Boloos.

**Lemma 17.2**: Let T be a consistent theory extending Q. Then the set of Godel numbers of theorems of T is not definable in T.
Here a definable set S means there is a predicate F(x) such that F(**a**) is correct under the standard interpretation of arithmetic if and only if **a** belongs to S , so F(x) and S have a similar extension, so to speak.

The proof of Lemma 17.2: Suppose F(y) defines the set S of Godel numbers of theorems of T. By diagonal lemma there is a sentence G such that
$$T\vdash G \leftrightarrow \lnot F(g)$$
with g is the Godel number of G. Then G is a theorem of T. **For if we assume G is not a theorem of T, then g is not in S, and since F(y) defines S, we have $T\vdash \lnot F(g)$**; but then since $T\vdash G \leftrightarrow \lnot F(g)$, we have $T\vdash G$ after all. But since G is a theorem of T, g is in S, and so we have $T\vdash F(g)$, but then since $T\vdash G \leftrightarrow \lnot F(g)$, we have $T\vdash \lnot G$ , and T is inconsistent.

I have 2 problems regarding the above proof.

1. I don't quite understand the bold text in the proof. If g is not in S, $\lnot F(g)$ is true, but this does not entail $T\vdash \lnot F(g)$.
2. While reading the "Introduction to Godel's incompleteness theorems" by Peter Smith, I also came through the assertion that the set of theorems T is definable (or expressible in the author's terms) by the predicate Prov(x), while the set of true sentences is not even definable (Tarski's theorem). Does this assertion contradict the lemma?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; see page 207:

> If $T$ is a consistent theory in the language of arithmetic, we say a set $S$ is *defined
> in* $T$ by $D(x)$ if for all $n$, if $n$ is in $S$, then $D(\overline n)$ is a theorem of $T$ [i.e. $T \vdash D(\overline n)$], and if $n$ is not in $S$, then $\lnot D(\overline n)$ is a theorem of $T$.

*Note*: I've used $\overline n$ for the *numeral* corresponding to number $n$.

Thus, the argument is: "we assume G is not a theorem of T", i.e. $T \nvdash G$, and thus "g is not in S".

But "F(y) defines S",  i.e. $T \vdash \lnot F(\overline g)$ iff $g \notin S$.

Thus, from "g is not in S" it follows that $T \vdash \lnot F(\overline g)$.

---

Unfortunately, the name is the same but the definition is different from the [Definable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_set) of model theory:

> a set $A\subseteq M$ is definable in $\mathcal {M}$ if and only if there exists a formula $\varphi$ such that for all $a\in M$

> $$a \in A \text  { iff } \mathcal {M}\models \varphi [a].$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was mistaken about the definition of arithmetical definability and definability. Everything makes sense now.