Why does the existence of the $\text{Prf}(x,y)$ predicate not contradict the result that provability is undefinable in first order logic?
On the one hand, we have the following meta-theorem (Lemma 17.2 in Boolos et al. Computability and Logic):

(Lemma 17.2) Let $T$ be a consistent theory extending $\textbf{Q}$. Then the set of Gödel numbers of theorems of $T$ is not definable in $T$.

where the concept of "definable" was explained on the last chapter:

We say a formula $F(x)$ of the language of arithmetic arithmetically defines a set
$S$ of natural numbers if and only if for all natural numbers $a$ we have $Sa$ if and only if
$F(\textbf{a})$ is correct. We say the set $S$ is arithmetically definable, or arithmetical for short, if some formula arithmetically defines it.

However, the predicate $\text{Prf}(x,y)$ meaning "$x$ proves $y$" or, more precisely, "$x$ is the Gödel number of a proof of the sentence with the Gödel number $y$" is sometimes constructed. See here for an example. Would this not mean that the set of Gödel numbers of theorems in $T$ is definably by
$$\exists x\text{Prf}(x,y)?$$

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3980961: there are two definitions of definability, and under the stronger one being used here $\exists x\ \mathrm{Proof}(x, y)$ does not define provability.
